# Xceed DecimalUpDown - maximum binding working strangely

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xceed

I have `DecimalUpDown` on form

```
<xceed:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding Value}" FormatString="C2" Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}" Minimum="0">
```

`Value` is `decimal`.

`MaxValue` is `decimal`.

Double checked.

---

When my `MaxValue` is for example `83,64` and I enter `90`

[image]

then hit enter

[image]

it changes to `9` instead of `83,64`.

---

When I enter `723`

[image]

and hit enter

[image]

it changes to `72` instead of `83,64`.

---

I suspect it's something with this `Maximum` constraint because when I remove it

```
<xceed:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding Value}" FormatString="C2" Minimum="0">
```

and enter - for example - `48,65`

[image]

and hit enter

[image]

it stays on this value as it should.

**Am I overlooking something or is this some kind of decimal separator bug?**

Comment: I get the same effect both with decimal & integer fields - what seems to happen if the input value exceeds the maximum value then rather than set the max value, characters are deleted from the end of the string until the value is within range. I do not know if this is documented behaviour or a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Maximum is 83,64 and you enter 90, you are out of range, so an exception is raised and the last valid value entered is kept : 9.

If you want to set the Maximum value when the value entered is greater than the Maximum, set the property ClipValueToMinMax to true. Entering 90 will result in 83,64.